# sent an object to my server with ajax, cant seem to get the data with php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have sent two pieces of data to my PHP with this bit of AJAX:

```
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "php/addUser.php";
    var username = document.getElementById("newUserName").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("newUserPass").value;
    var newUsername = "user_name="+username;
    var newPassword="password="+password;
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            var return_data = request.responseText;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    };
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    request.send({newUsername,newPassword}); // Actually execute the request
```

This is the PHP code that is supposed to take these two pieces of data and plug it into my mysql database.

```
//Connect to the database

$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port)or die(mysql_error());

$userName=$_POST['newUsername'];
$userPassword=$_POST['newPassword'];

$query="INSERT INTO users(user_name,password)
VALUES('$userName','$userPassword')";

if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}

$connection->close();
```

When the AJAX is run, it runs with no errors and sends the data to my PHP code on my server. The PHP code then runs and completes with no errors but then when I check my database the new user is inserted into the database but it is empty. I'm pretty sure it's something in my PHP code, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and add some error checking to your queries.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `request.send()` should be a URL-encoded string, not an object.

```
request.send(newUsername + '&' + newPassword);
```

Note that you should also use `encodeURIComponent` when setting the variables, in case they contain special URL characters.

```
var newUsername = "user_name=" + encodeURIComponent(username);
var newPassword = "password=" + encodeURIComponent(password);
```

Also, your object syntax was incorrect. The syntax for objects is

```
{ prop1: value1, prop2: value2, ... }
```

`{ var1, var2 }` should have given you a syntax error.

You're also using the wrong `$_POST` keys. The keys should match the parameter names before `=`, not the IDs of the form fields.

```
$userName = $_POST['user_name'];
$userPassword = $_POST['password'];
```

You should also use a prepared statement in the PHP instead of variable substitution, to prevent SQL injection problems.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = $connection->prepare("ss", $userName, $userPassword);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $stmt->error;
}
$connection->close();
```

Comment: noticed the wrong object syntax like 10 seconds after i posted this question (product of me being frustrated haha). Ive tried everything you suggested and im still getting the same errors, and after some testing the php seems to somehow be getting 0 from the ajax.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the error that @frz3993 noticed in his answer.

Comment: With all those changes i was finally able to get it to work, i really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You post `user_name` and `password` with ajax. But in your PHP code you used `$_POST['newUsername']` and `$_POST['newPassword']`. You can change either the ajax or PHP.
Example:

```
$userName = $_POST['user_name'];
$userPassword=$_POST['password'];
```

And your request from ajax should be

```
request.send(newUsername+"&"+newPassword);
```